# Unable to decipher DIV tag with CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, html

I've got this `DIV` tag that has a class definition in it.

```
    <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
```

I've searched the entire project, but I can't find this class anywhere by using the text search feature.

Currently, the `DIV` is too wide, and I need to trim it down a bit.

Whenever I remove the `class="clear hideSkiplink"` reference, the `DIV` tag immediately grows much too large.

I inherited this project after the website developer left. I'm good with C# and WinForms, but not really this web stuff.

Could someone help me out, please?

**Solved!**

I found `.clear { clear: both; }` burried in the file `StyleSheet.css`, but I could not find the `hideSkiplink` word anywhere in my project.

So, I took the `hideSkiplink` word off, and the rendered page did not change in the browser.

Apparently, all I was seeing was controlled by the one `clear` word in the `DIV` tag.

My tag now reads:

```
    <div class="clear">
```

Thanks, JLevett!

Comment: Presumably it'd be in a css file as .clear {} or .hideSkiplink {}.  See if the html doc uses a link tag to pull in a CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'clear' and 'hideSkiplink' are too different classes, not one.

Try searching for those individual phrases within your project.

Comment: There's  also a possibility that, while `hideSkipLink` does not exist in the CSS, it could be used by any JS code running on the page.

Answer (score 1):

if you have firebug, go to HTML tab, find your element and click on int, I made you a screen of this page as an example, the red circles show the class names and the green circles show you the css source file. You might as well ctrl+click on the source files and they open in a new browser window :) [image]